# Fixed position height is bigger than browser window by percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to open a lightbox on click to an element. I have give position `fixed` to the lightbox(just div with id value fixed).
Here lightbox id is `fixed` in the [js example](http://jsfiddle.net/zT284/)

**CSS**

```
#fixed {
  position:fixed;
       margin:0 auto;
       width:50%;
       height:50%;
       background-color: red;
       display: none;

       z-index:9999999;
}
#left{
    float:left;
    width:30%;
}
#right{
    float:left;
    width:70%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="fixed">
    <div id="left">content</div>
    <div id="right">content</div>
</div>
<div id="check">
    Open
</div>
<div id="check2">
    close
</div>
```

I used **jQuery** to center align the div vertically

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var winWidth=$(window).width();
    var winHeight= $(window).height();
    var divWidth= $('#fixed').width();
    var divHeight= $('#fixed').height();
    var top = (winHeight/2)-(divHeight/2);
    var left = (winWidth/2)-(divWidth/2);
     alert(winHeight);
    alert(divHeight);
    alert(top);
    $('#fixed').css('top',top);
    $('#fixed').css('left',left);
    $('#check').click(function(){
        $('#fixed').fadeIn(300);
    });
    $('#check2').click(function(){
        $('#fixed').fadeOut(300);
    });
});
```

The above fiddle works fine but the same concept i use in my localhost. There the window size is bigger than jsfiddle.

The div is not center aligning vertically. 
am getting the alert of div height size larger than the window height size so it is not placing at center it is placing at the bottom.

Here is the alert value when i run the script

```
798
950
-76
```

798 is the browser height i believe and 950 is the div height final top value is -76.

I don't have any idea on this even i have given 50% of width and height for the lightbox(div) in css.

Why am i getting the higher value? I want to position it vertically center align can anyone help?

Comment: Could be a CSS issue  e.g min-height set for DIV in your localhost copy site

Comment: CSS is same as `#fixed` in my local too and also i checked it is not redefined in any place @A.Wolff Thanks

Comment: Some other content inside #left and #right of the #fixed div in my local. Is this a problem? @A.Wolff

Comment: If DIV's content make it beeing taller than window, ya, it is a problem. Couldn't you just try to debug it using less content for DIV on your localhost?!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any errors with that JSFiddle - it's loading vertically aligned for me.

My only suggestion would to declare the height of the element containing #fixed to be 100%. I would assume that might be the body element in this case. That way the fixed div is sure to be 50% of 100%, rather than 50% of 0%, which some browsers may set it as.

Comment: For which should i give 100% height @Jonathon Blok

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked into the Javascript code. But since you have `width` and `height` set to  `50%`, you can just position `top` and `left` at `25%`, no calculation necessary

```
#fixed {
    position:fixed;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
}
```

See modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zT284/2/)

Comment: I got this earlier i tried it is working fine. I want to know is there  any problem in the design because in jquery calculation am getting wrong right. And wrong aligning too. Is that a problem? @Olaf Dietsche

Comment: When I test http://jsfiddle.net/zT284/show/ in Firefox 20 or Chromium 25, it is properly centered vertically and horizontally.